# com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadException: Type has not been loaded occurred invoking methods

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

Need help on writing Junit.
i am getting error "*com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadException: Type has not been loaded occurred invoking methods.*" while hitting controller method from my Junit test class.
**modelView = avamar.getCompGuidePage(productVersion , avamarComponent, model );** above line showing the classNotLoadException dut to this.
Debug is not allow me to enter in the controller method breakpoint.

Here is the test and Actual class.

Test class

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.emc.brsit.avamar.vo.AvamarAllComponentsVO;
import com.emc.brsit.common.util.CustomCompGuideException;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:/Project/applicationContext servlet.xml")
public class AvamarControllerTest {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
                    .getLogger(AvamarControllerTest.class);
    @Mock
    private AvamarController avamar;
    @Mock
    private AvamarAllComponentsVO avamarComponent;

    /*@Before
    public void setupMock() {
        avamar = mock(AvamarController.class);
        avamarComponent = mock(AvamarAllComponentsVO.class);
    }*/

    @Before
    public void setupMock() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCompGuidePage()  {
        String productVersion ="7.5";
        Model model = null;
        ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView();
        try {
            modelView = avamar.getCompGuidePage(productVersion , avamarComponent, model );
        } catch (CustomCompGuideException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String abc = "new";
    }
}
```

**Actual Controller Class method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAvamarCompGuidePage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getCompGuidePage(
@ModelAttribute("productVersion") String productVersion,
    @ModelAttribute("allComponentsVO") AvamarAllComponentsVO allComponentsVO,
            Model model) throws CustomCompGuideException{

        LOGGER.debug("AvamarController::getCompGuidePage()::Start::");
        //System.out.println("--------------Controller--------------");
        try {
        model.addAttribute("featureInstant",
                avamarOSBO.getApp_Hype_Feat_Filters("Features"));
    model.addAttribute("clientOSGrouped",avamarOSBO.getClientOSGroupedBY());
        model.addAttribute("clientOSGroupedos_vendor",
                avamarOSBO.getClientOSGroupedByVendor());
        model.addAttribute("clientOS", avamarOSBO.getClientOS());

        model.addAttribute("ndmpOSGrouped",avamarOSBO.getNDMPOSGroupedBY());

    // model.addAttribute("features",
        // avamarOSBO.getApp_Hype_Feat_Filters("Extended Retention"));

        // model.addAttribute("featOS", avamarOSBO.getFeatType2OS());
model.addAttribute("hypeOSGroupedType2",avamarOSBO.getHypeOSGroupedBYType2());


        model.addAttribute("featOSGroupedos_vendor",
                avamarOSBO.getFeatType2OSGroupedByVendor());
            // Important for Navigation
        model.addAttribute("link",productVersion);
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.debug("SITE DOWN DUE TO ERROR::-->" + ex.getMessage());
            throw new CustomCompGuideException(ex.getMessage());
        }
        LOGGER.debug("AvamarController::getCompGuidePage()::END::");
            return new ModelAndView("AvamarCompGuideApp");
    }
```

Comment: why are you acting on a mocked object? instead of on a concrete implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing method on mock of AvamarController.

Try below code. Have added comments in caps where ever made change

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:/Project/applicationContext servlet.xml")
public class AvamarControllerTest {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
                    .getLogger(AvamarControllerTest.class);

    // REMOVED MOCK HERE
    private AvamarController avamar;

    @Mock
    private AvamarAllComponentsVO avamarComponent;

    /*@Before
    public void setupMock() {
        avamar = mock(AvamarController.class);
        avamarComponent = mock(AvamarAllComponentsVO.class);
    }*/

    @Before
    public void setupMock() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // INJECT MOCKED DEPENDENCES IF ANY
        avamar = new AvamarController(...inject mocked dependencies if any....);

       // DEPENDING ON WHAT YOU WANNA TEST, MOCK RETURN VALUES...One example below
       Mockito.when(avamarComponent. getApp_Hype_Feat_Filters(any()))
       .thenReturn(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetCompGuidePage()  {
        String productVersion ="7.5";

        // THIS WILL THROW NULL EXCEPTION. NOT SURE IF ITS INTENTSIONAL
        Model model = null;
        ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView();
        try {
            modelView = avamar.getCompGuidePage(productVersion , avamarComponent, model );
        } catch (CustomCompGuideException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String abc = "new";
    }
}
```